# How to install OpenRasta Visual Studio Templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, installation, project, openrasta

I know I'm missing something stupid.
I followed the instructions in [wiki](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki/Downloading-and-Compiling-OpenRasta) and I got few zip files in `bin\Release\vside` folder, which I'm sure are visual studio templates. But I don't know how to install them to be available in Visual Studio new project dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the zip files to My Doucmetns/Visual Studio 2008/Templates

We don't support those templates anymore though as no one is there to maintain them anymore (they are only for vs 2008)

Comment: Is there a set of steps anywhere for when not using the templates? As I am looking at 2.1 spit into it's parts but there is no documentation on getting started.

Comment: The quickstarts are being updated and you can expect something next week. The simplest way is to update to openwrap 2.0 and use the new create-openrastasite command, which gives you templates for 2.1.